# Two numbers can't be perfect squares at the same time

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that $a+b$ and $ab-1$, $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, cannot be both perfect squares.

My idea is to write $a+b=x^2$ and $ab-1=y^2$,then multiply this equations and after that add 1 to the both side of equation. I have $(a+b)(ab-1)+1=(xy)^2+1$. We know that expression $x^2+1$ has no divisors of form 4k+3, and I want to find that left side of equation has a divisor of form $4k+3$,what is contradiction, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: I can suggest a different method. Will it do?

Comment: what method ?i can try.

Comment: Show that wlog $a\equiv3\bmod8$, and then $a$ must have a divisor that's $3\bmod4$.

Comment: This is equivalent to saying that the roots of $T^2-x^2T+(y^2+1)$ cannot be simultaneously integers.

Answer (score 1):

The squares mod 4 are 0 and 1; the squares mod 8 are 0, 1, and 4.

If $ab-1$ is a square, then $ab$ is 1 or 2 mod 4. If $ab\equiv1\bmod4$, then $a\equiv b\equiv1\bmod4$, or $a\equiv b\equiv3\bmod4$. In either case, $a+b\equiv2\bmod4$ is not a square. Thus, we may assume $ab\equiv2\bmod4$, whence also $ab\equiv2\bmod8$.

This implies one of the two numbers $a,b$ is even, the other, odd. We assume, without loss of generality, that $a$ is odd. $ab\equiv2\bmod8$ then has the solutions $(a,b)\equiv(1,2),(3,6),(5,2),(7,6)\bmod8$. The only one compatible with $a+b$ being square is $(3,6)$, so $a\equiv3\bmod8$, so $a\equiv3\bmod4$. So the prime factors of $a$ can't all be 1 or 2 mod 2; $a$ must have a prime factor $p\equiv3\bmod4$.

But also $p$ divides $ab=y^2+1$, contradiction since $-1$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $p$.